# What is wrong with my 'except' code here?

Tags: python, python-3.x, error-handling

I am learning python and am working through some `try` and `except` codes. What is wrong here?

The code aims to convert the input in to an integer unless it is not numeric.

```
try:
    def get_integer(my_var):
        try:
            x = round(my_var, 0)
            return x
        except:  
            y = int(my_var)
            return y
        except:
            pass
except:
    print("Cannot convert!")       

#Below are some lines of code that will test your function.
#You can change the value of the variable(s) to test your
#function with different inputs.
#
#If your function works correctly, this will originally
#print: 5, Cannot convert!, and 5.

print(get_integer("5"))
print(get_integer("Boggle."))
print(get_integer(5.1))
```

The error:

```
  File "GetInteger.py", line 19

             ^
SyntaxError: default 'except:' must be last
Command exited with non-zero status 1
```

But except is last. What am I missing?

Comment: This question should have been asked in StackOverflow forum and not here as this place is intended for posts about working code that could be improved or/and reviewed

Comment: Chill out. First post here and three downvotes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## TL; DR

Basically, all of your `except` blocks are "defaults", hence the error message. To have multiple `except` clauses, you must tell to all of them (except the last one) what they're supposed to catch (what used functions can - and will - raise)

## What's happening ?

The reason is quite simple here.

`try..except` blocks can accept many `except` blocks in order to do things in case of different type of exceptions. By default (and I don't really recommend it, because you don't have a clear idea of what's going on) it's a block like this one:

```
try:
    i_will_raise_some_exception()
except:
    # fix me up before you go!
```

This will catch every exception raised because we didn't tell the except block what to catch. You might already understand your problem here. Here's a second example:

```
try:
    # I used this condition to have a somewhat believable (yet dumb) way to say
    # I can send multiple exceptions within the same try block
    if (some_weird_condition):
        print(1/0)
    i_will_raise_some_exception()

except DivisionError:
    # woops!

# Exception is optional here, as it catches everything
except Exception:
    # catch any other exceptions and fix me up before you go!
```

You can find more information [here](https://docs.python.org/3.7/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions).

Comment: Nice answer, however it an off-topic question. Please don't answer off-topic questions as it promotes behavior we don't want. To discourage you from doing this again I've _downvoted_ this. Otherwise if you posted answers like this to on-topic questions it'd be a happy upvote :)

Comment: Oh, ok @Peilonrayz. Well, at least, I'll know for the next one I might answer